# Ruby on Rails: Finding Records using passed parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making an online magazine style website and am having difficulties getting the syntax right for my final part of the project. The relationships are working as they should I am just having trouble calling the intended records.

Each `post` belongs to a `category` with `category_id` being the foreign key. When a user clicks this link, `<%= link_to 'News', categories_path(:category_id => 1) %>`, I'd like for them to be brought to an index page showing only `posts` with a `category_id` matching the parameter in the URL.

I've been messing around in the `categories_controller.rb` for almost two hours now with no luck. Anyone be so kind as to throw this noob a bone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few components of what you're trying to do.  We'll start with the routing side, and make our way to the controller.

First, you need to make the proper routes.  Since the post belongs to a category, you will need to have the category id in order to handle performing any sort of operations on the posts.  So we'd need a route like `/category/:category_id/posts/:id`.  Luckily, Rails has something to handle this.  If you nest a `resources` within a `resources`, it'll generate these routes.  So, we end up with this:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :posts
end
```

And that will get you what you want in terms of routes.  But now we have to actually implement it.  So, we're going to need to take a look at the controllers.  If you notice, all of those routes have a `:category_id` - so looking up the category shouldn't be too difficult:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_category

private

  def load_category
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  end

end
```

Now, you have the category loaded, and it shouldn't be too difficult to implement the other methods from there:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_category

  def index
    @posts = @category.posts
  end

  def show
    @post = @category.posts.find(id: params[:id])
  end

  # ...
end
```

In order to reference the Post index path, you'll have to use `category_posts_path` helper.

Comment: Thank you Jermy you're very kind.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to use an existing route to handle some new functionality (for which it was incidentally not designed). That `categories_path` route is meant to take you to your category index.

You need to create a method in your controller to perform the functionality you want to see.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def posts_by_category
    @posts_by_category = Post.where("category_id = ?", params[:category_id])
  end

  ...
end
```

Then you're going to need a view to display your `@posts_by_category` array (I'll leave this exercise to you).

And now for the key to your problem: you need a route pointing to the `posts_by_category` method.

```
get 'posts/posts_by_category' => 'posts#posts_by_category'
```

Now you should be able to create your link with the correct route:

```
<%= link_to 'News', posts_by_category_path(:category_id => 1) %>
```